# do you want ssh for your instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, ssh

as I'm using aws I'm looking into two tutorials just to make sure I do it right. and I'm at a step to do eb init, and it asks "do you want ssh for your instance?" one tutorial says I should say yes and the other says i should put no...isn't ssh the one that connects my laptop with amazon's network shouldn't I put yes for this?but why does the tutorial say I should put no

Comment: Can you update the question with which tutorials you're looking at? Would help to get a context of the tutorials.

Comment: @TristanTao one is paid one the other is https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 2):

The advice against using `ssh` comes from a well-meaning bunch that wants us all to create reproducible configurations that don't require administrators to login in order to periodically tweak the config.  It also becomes another interface that must be secured.

Ideally, everything you need is independent of `ssh` because you are providing some internet-accessible service like a webserver/database/etc.

If your process isn't that mature yet, it's acceptable to enable `ssh`, but you should strive towards not needing it.

Comment: so if my project isn't perfect and I need to twerk the project as I go, I should enable ssh? it this what you are saying?

Comment: @emfour yes, that's what he is saying. You will probably need ssh at some point when you are initially building your application just so you can login to the server and see why a deployment isn't working or to look at a log file or something.

Comment: Maintaining ssh key in multiple server definitely not a fun job.